# Adding relative spherical coordinates to absolute Lat/Lon/Alt coordinates

Tags: python, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, spherical-geometry

I have an absolute position of an observer given in Lat/Lon/Alt (on earth, ellipsoid). The observer observes an object and measures azimuth (angle), elevation (angle) and range (NM) to this object relative to himself (real sphere, no ellipsoid).

From that data, how can I compute Lat/Lon/Alt coordinates (on earth, ellipsoid) of the observed object?

So far, I am using the following approximation, but I am looking for a more mathematical correct/precise approach:

```
2D_range = range * cos(elevation)
obj_lat = obs_lat + 2D_range * cos(azimuth) / 60
obj_lon = obs_lon + 2D_range * sin(azimuth) / (60 * cos(obj_lat))

alt_delta = range * sin(elevation)
obj_alt = obs_alt + alt_delta
```

The problem with this approximation is, that it does not take into account the ellipsoid shape of the earth.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  What have you tried?

Comment: @PolyGeo I added my current approximation. Concerning the GIS software: Consider it being Python. For a starter, the usage of library functions would be ok, but I am more interested in the mathematical (language/software independent) approach.